# Accessing DOM element by Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have page In which if you click on the `INV001` link it will open a pop window. Am trying to access the `foo` object in the popUp window using document.getElementById('foo') but am getting null

Below is the webpage code

```
<tbody class="">
    <tr class="tipAdded">
        <td class="first">
            <div style="display:none" class="renderedValue">
              INV001
            </div><input value="2" name="instanceId0.id" type="hidden" class="check">
        </td>
        <td class="typeString  ">
            <div class="data typeString">
                <a tooltip="" class="linkedOverlay " title="" href="/CP/user/show.do?screenId=273&amp;mode=show&amp;referringAttributeId=1329&amp;key=&amp;entityInstanceId=2&amp;parentEntityId=&amp;parentInstanceId=&amp;parentInstanceKey=&amp;parentFieldName=">
                    INV001        
              </a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>


<div class="ui">
    <div class="literal">
        <div id="one">
<object id="foo" name="foo" type="text/html" data="../../QuickInvoice/printInvoiceSummary.do?InvoiceId=2" style="height:700px;width:750px"></object>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

popup window's code

```
<head>
        <title> Invoice Summary </title>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                 function getPrintData()
                {
                    var invoice = document.getElementByID('foo');
                    printHTML(invoice.data);

                }

function printHTML(htmlString) {
    var newIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    newIframe.width = '1px';
    newIframe.height = '1px';
    newIframe.src = 'about:blank';

    // for IE wait for the IFrame to load so we can access contentWindow.document.body
    newIframe.onload = function() {
        var script_tag = newIframe.contentWindow.document.createElement("script");
        script_tag.type = "text/javascript";
        var script = newIframe.contentWindow.document.createTextNode('function Print(){ window.focus(); window.print(); }');
        script_tag.appendChild(script);

        newIframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = htmlString;
        newIframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(script_tag);

        // for chrome, a timeout for loading large amounts of content
        setTimeout(function() {
            newIframe.contentWindow.Print();
            newIframe.contentWindow.document.body.removeChild(script_tag);
            newIframe.parentElement.removeChild(newIframe);
        }, 200);
    };
    document.body.appendChild(newIframe);
}
                </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <caption align="left"><h2>Invoice Summary</h2></caption>
         <div style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0">
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <form>
                                <input id='printWindow' type='button' onClick="getPrintData()" value='Print' class='NonPrintable' />
                            </form>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>        
        </div>  
        <table cellspacing='0' id='header'>     
            <tr>
              <th>Tracking Id</th>
              <td><%=invoice.get("Reference ID").toString()%></td>            
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Upload Date</th>
              <td><%=invoice.get("Upload Date").toString()%></td>             
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Status</th>
              <td><%=invoice.get("Status").toString()%></td>              
            </tr>           
        </table>                

    </body>
</html>
```

`foo` is the popup window's id and in getPrintData `invoice` value is null, Can someone help me to access this `foo` in pop up window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is currently implemented, `document.getElementByID('foo')` is trying to find the element "foo" within the context of the popup document (printInvoiceSummary.do) which currently does not have an element with id of "foo". If I am understanding correctly, you just need to access object with id of "foo" on the parent document:

```
var invoice = top.document.getElementById('foo');
```

Alternately, you can also access the same object using the following:

```
var invoice = window.frameElement;
```

Comment: with `top.document.getElementByID('foo')` am getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error

Comment: Realized you have a capitalization error in "getElementByID". Needed to be "getElementById". Edited above in my example.